# Display a list of products in a custom Shopify app

Tags: python, json, flask, python-requests, shopify

I have updated the code to the following:

```
@app.route('/products_linking', methods=['GET'])
# @helpers.verify_web_call
def products_linking():
    shop = request.args.get('shop')
    global ACCESS_TOKEN
    if ACCESS_TOKEN:
        url = f'https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/'
        def get_products():
            endpoint = 'products.json'
            r = requests.get(url + endpoint)
            return r.json()
        products = get_products()
        print(products)
        print(shop)
        return render_template('products_linking.html', shop=shop, products=products)
```

When I click on the link for /products_linking in my app I get {'errors': '[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)'} for products and 'None' for the shop variable. If the code inside the if ACCESS_TOKEN: block is being executed why am I getting an invalid access token error? Also why is the value of the shop variable coming back as None?

Answer (score 1):

You're hitting a wrong URL. The Shopify API endpoint to get products is

`https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-10/products.json`

You also need to include an access token in the `X-Shopify-Access-Token` header.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have updated the question

Comment: You haven't included the X-Shopify-Access-Token header. It should be the password that you can get from your [private app settings](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/apps/private-apps#generate-credentials-from-the-shopify-admin).

Comment: As for the shop variable, are you passing it in query parameters? For example, .../products_linking?shop=corpdiskdev

Comment: Yes when the app is initially loaded up I get this: shop=corpdiskdev.myshopify.com included in a long string including things like code and hmac and host. Sorry I am very new to this, I'm using the example i found at https://github.com/garettB/shopify-flask-example/tree/master/src

Comment: I have added new routes but I think there is an issue with authentication to those routes. The other functions have the @helpers.verify_web_call decorator uncommented but if I uncomment the decorator on the functions I have added I get         hmac None
        data b''

Comment: Also this is a custom app not a private app if that helps. Not sure what the difference is but we are not making a private app

Comment: Sorry it's actually a public app not custom